# problem with classes not found during PlayPlugin.enhance

Tags: plugins, playframework, bytecode-manipulation, javassist

I'm experimenting with a basic bytecode enhancement in a Play plugin, but when it tries to operate on the `ApplicationClasses.ApplicationClass` that it's given, the class can't be found.

```
public void enhance(ApplicationClasses.ApplicationClass applicationClass)
    throws NotFoundException, IOException, CannotCompileException 
{
    ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass ctClass = classPool.get(applicationClass.name);
    ...
}
```

The exception is

```
Oops: NotFoundException An unexpected error occured caused by exception NotFoundException: controllers.CRUD

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying AccessControlPlugin@1a5db4b on controllers.CRUD
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:215)
...
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: controllers.CRUD
        at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:436)
        at AccessControlPlugin.enhance(AccessControlPlugin.java:19)
```

The Play framework is calling the `enhance` method.  Shouldn't it know better than to process classes that aren't available yet?  How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you increase the plug-in's load order in `play.plugins` to 1000, i.e. after the built-in plug-ins? I haven't seen this problem with enhancement, although I have had problems with the plug-in's enhance method not being called for certain classes.

Comment: I tried a variety of values from 1 to 10000.  Sometimes it changes which class it can't find, but none of them allowed it to work.